# Mysql query slow performance

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table with 500k rows. I have specific table which takes really long time to run every query.

One of the queries is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM player_data
WHERE  `user_id` =  '61120'
  AND  `opzak` =  'ja'
ORDER BY opzak_nummer ASC
```

the `opzak_nummer` column is a `tinyint` with a number.

EXPLAIN:

[image]

Is there any way to improve this query performance and the general of this query/table?

The table name is player_data and includes about 25 columns, most of them are integers with values of stats.

The index is `id` AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: Is that you are using any index.

Comment: Performance questions should include EXPLAIN ANALYZE and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. Slow is a relative term and we need a real value to compare. MySQL Also Please read [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Explain SELECT * 
FROM player_data
WHERE  `user_id` =  '61120'
AND  `opzak` =  'ja'
ORDER BY opzak_nummer ASC

Comment: Check this and update your question

Comment: one thing you could do is remove the quotes around user_id, provided that the column in the table is not varchar.  This will do an implicit cast which will adversely affect performance.  Otherwise, the posters above are correct:  without analyze or at least index definitions against the table (assuming it's actually a table and not a view) it is impossible to create a blanket "do this and it will improve" statement.

Comment: @khalid Didn't know about the EXPLAIN. updated my question, thanks.

Comment: @TGray thanks, didn't know such as things can affect performance. if you mean`ANALYZE player_data` so the status is ok. couldn't understand your question about index.

Comment: create a composite index on user_id and opzak.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE pokemon_speler ADD INDEX index_name (user_id, opzak);`

Comment: It might take few minutes.

Comment: Keep in mind that it will take time to deliver 282K rows!

Comment: Is that your query is still running.

Comment: @khalid I don't get, What does running `ALTER TABLE pokemon_speler ADD INDEX index_name (user_id, opzak);` will do or change?

Comment: You need to run that query, it will alter table and add index. You can read more details here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: In case it will make trouble, how I can revert the index and return the table to the original?

Comment: In case you can delete index also.

Comment: `DROP INDEX index_name ON tbl_name` you can use this query, but correct table name and index name

Comment: The index improved the speed really awesome! but some queries didn't work and crashed the website. How I can know what are the indexes I should do? query with INNER JOIN didn't work, which is joinined another table using `item_id` on my table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124703/discussion-between-khalid-and-theunreal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run that query, it will alter table and add index. You can read more details here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-index.html

`ALTER TABLE pokemon_speler ADD INDEX index_name (user_id, opzak);`

Comment: thanks, there are still some problems. Let you know in discussion

Answer (score 0):

The optimal index for that query is either of these:

```
INDEX(user_id, opzak, opzak_nummer)
INDEX(opzak, user_id, opzak_nummer)
```

The first two columns do the filtering; the last avoids a tmp table and sort by consuming the `ORDER BY`.

Is any combination of columns 'unique' (other than `id`)?  If so, we might be able to make it run even faster.

Comment: `id is the only unique. I didn't get the first part of your answer, what's `INDEX(user_id, opzak, opzak_nummer) INDEX(opzak, user_id, opzak_nummer)` and how do I avoid the tmp table?

Comment: Either of those indexes should avoid the tmp table for _that_ query.  See [_Cookbook_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/)